# retrieve static data from firebase with angularfire2

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

I know the whole purpose of angularfire2 is the fluid back and forth sync of your app and firebase via the observable. I use that functionality all over my app but in one spot there is a specific need to get data as a fixed copy that doesn't change.

Assuming database looks like this

```
// firebase is something like:
// {  items: {
//      item1: { ... },
//      item2: { ... },
//      item3: { ... }
//    }
// }

myList$: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
myList: any[];
this.myList$ = this.af.database.list('/items');
this.myList$.subscribe(questions => {
    this.myList = questions; // can this.myList ever be frozen?
});
```

In other words, in the above example, is there any possible way to easily get `items` as it is in that exact moment and not, for example, updating when/if an `item4` shows up?

Comment: You can store it as a string and when you need to use it, parse it to JSON again. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If you compose it using the `first` operator, the observable will complete upon emitting the first value, so  you won't be notified of any further changes:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

myList$: Observable<any[]>;
myList: any[];

this.myList$ = this.af.database.list('/items').first();
this.myList$.subscribe(questions => { this.myList = questions; });
```

And, as it completes, there's no need to unsubscribe.

Regarding the question in your comment, no there's no reason the first call would work and subsequent calls would return an empty array. The only explanation is that the subsequent locations contain no data.

Also, with your function, it would make more sense to return a promise - rather than to subscribe and manipulate an object property (with no mechanism for indicating when said property has been modified):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

myFunc(location: string): Promise<any[]> {
    return this.af.database
        .list('/items/' + location)
        .first()
        .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. I do run in to a problem when I put this in a function and change the location around. http://pastebin.com/reu78FgJ It gets the first call correct but every call after that has an empty [] for 'questions =>'. Any idea why / around that?

Comment: Updated the answer.